# How to use save data in shared peferences file from fragment

Tags: android-activity, sharedpreferences

I seem to be struggling with saving data from fragment.java file in shared preference file. I have a register xml file which contains empty student details and a register button beneath. I need to know how to save the data i enter in the edit boxes provided in the egister xml file using Shared Preferences. My project contains an activity with a login, register and welcome fragment files.

Comment: Your question doesn't show a minimum understanding about Android layout, Activity and Fragments. Please put specific questions in StackOverflow

Comment: @ReazMurshed I think the question is very clear, at least it's clear for me. He wants to save, using Shared Preferences, the data that he inputs in some editboxes he have inside a fragment.

Comment: I have found the answer i was looking for.